# In nifi how to call a rest service using groovy script

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

In nifi how to call POST json data and get json response. I have tried to use the HTTPbuilder by adding HTTPbuilder library. But getting exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:775)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

Comment: How did you "add the library"? You will need to provide the JAR in a directory which the `ExecuteScript` processor is configured to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the sample to to call POST rest service in GroovyScript

```
        def jsonBody= '{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"match\":{\"FlowID\":' + flowID + '}}]}}}'
        def url ="http://localhost/rest"
        def post = new URL(url).openConnection()
        post.setRequestMethod("POST")
        post.setDoOutput(true)
        post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
        post.getOutputStream().write(jsonBody.getBytes("UTF-8"))
        def w_getResponseCode = post.getResponseCode();
        def response = ""
        if (w_getResponseCode.equals(200)) {
            response = post.getInputStream().getText()
        }
```

//Parse response in json using JsonSlurper.

You can use the above code in ExecuteGroovyScript Processor or you can create json in ExecuteGroovyScript and then use InvokeHttp with POST http method